# Comment out flutter print statements in vs code

Tags: flutter, printing, visual-studio-code, comments

I would like to comment out all the print statements in my flutter code. I am using VS Code. I would also like to preserve the spacing if possible. I have tried some regular expressions but I am not able to capture the space before he print statement. Would anyone know the regex for find/replace in VS code to do this?

I am trying this `^(\s)*\1print`, but it says back references not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this worked pretty nicely:

Find: `^(\s*)print`

Replace: `$1// print`

Looks like we don't need to use back references in vs code. And remember to turn the little .* icon ON to allow regex search/replace.

Comment: somebody should make a vs code extension to do this